Help remembering name of a 70's slasher movie
Me and my friends saw a LOT of psycho/slasher movies in the 70's.  I have long been trying to discover the name of one. Typical group of young folks visit a remote house by a lake;  I believe they first encounter a trio of ominous hippies in town.  The ominous townies end up following them out to the house by the lake where they have fun methodically butchering the visitors (and their hosts?) before the tables are turned and the crazies themselves end up meeting gruesome deaths at the vengeful hands of the survivors and/or last-girl (or two?).
One scene had an older man splashing helplessly in the deep water of the lake -- one of the hippie killers (thin, mid 20's?) runs him down in a small fishing boat with an outboard motor, all the while laughing maniacally. 
The long haired hippie that drives the small boat was played by an actor who was in several such slasher/psycho films within a couple of years;  he was thin, mid-20's and had kind of a hawk nose and long hair.  I remember him representing my definition of the generic psycho killer for years afterward.

Can you add language and country?

They are cannibals?

David Hess was an actor well known for "Grindhouse" psycho films, including Last House on the Left, Hitch-Hike, and House on the Edge of the Park - none of which quite fit the description you provide...  If you check his page on IMDB, is he the actor in question?  (You'll have to check the earlier photos, of course.)  If so, that will help narrow it down...

1).  The movie was American, in english.  It was a low-budget movie, of the type of psycho/slasher killer that was popular at that time.  2).  No, the hippie crazies were not cannibals; they were just mean-spirited psycho killers that had fun tormenting their victims for fun.  3).  Many thanks for the David Hess tip but unfortunately that is not the guy I was thinking of and none of the films I found him associated with on IMDB were the movie I was looking for.  Hess' movies all looked "bigger budget" that the psycho/slasher schlock I am remembering.

Other than the driver of the boat being male, this sounds a whole lot like I Spit on Your Grave (1978). In this movie there are three antagonists, the tables turn on them, and the surviving female gets her revenge in gruesome fashion. At the end she even uses a boat motor to kill the remaining antagonist.
